# Get multiple post meta with WordPress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, ionic-framework

```
function my_rest_prepare_post( $data, $post, $request ) {
   $_data = $data->data;
   $_data[$field] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_field_key', true );
   $data->data = $_data;
   return $data;
}
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'my_rest_prepare_post', 10, 3 );
```

Above is the code I am using to include meta value in API. But I want to include multiple meta I tried adding different meta key separating with, in  `my_custom_field_key` but I displayed only first key's value.

And second problem it only displayed Meta value how can I include key:value in JSON response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying my accepted answer in this similar question, I've tested the working function in my local site.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_fields' );
function add_custom_fields() {
register_rest_field(
'post', 
'custom_fields', //New Field Name in JSON RESPONSEs
array(
'get_callback'    => 'get_custom_fields', // custom function name 
'update_callback' => null,
'schema'          => null,
 )
);
}
```

Then define your functions to get custom fields

```
function get_custom_fields( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
return get_post_meta( $object['id'] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`//returns an array of metadata
get_metadata('post', $post->ID)`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata

Comment: can you edit above code with 2 meta keys.. I tried but incorrect code gets my website down with server error and i have to edit with ftp. If not shall I replace get_post_meta with get_metadata and add multiple meta keys. Is this correct get_metadata('post', $post->ID, $meta_key); with $meta_key being array containing all meta keys.